# REST API call to remove contacts from a journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I am trying to remove contacts from a journey using [REST API call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/contactExitRequest.htm) but keep getting the 202 response with errors. 
Not sure if I am using the wrong definition key, or if there is a mistake somewhere else.

This is the call I am making using POSTMAN:

```
[
    {
        "ContactKey": "0031t00000YEM4ZAAX",
        "DefinitionKey": "E70C07D7-6398-4406-9358-801EF4F831F5"
    }
]
```

And the response that I am getting, no matter which JourneyID I use, or whether I include "Versions" in my call:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "contactKey": "0031t00000YEM4ZAAX",
            "definitionKey": "E70C07D7-6398-4406-9358-801EF4F831F5",
            "status": [
                {
                    "version": 0,
                    "message": "Exit request Ignored - Invalid Interaction"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried using both JourneyID and VersionID in my calls, the result is the same.
I am getting JourneyID and VersionID from the [_Journey Data View](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_journey.htm&type=5) - maybe that is the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the REST API CALL in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getInteractionCollection.htm to retrieve the DefinitionKey of your journey.
The response body is like:

```
{
    "count": 16,
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "links": {},
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "ed52669e-408e-416c-9d85-XXXXXXXXX", //The journey ID
            "key": "b3218598-3671-bcd1-223a-XXXXXXX",//The journey Key
            "name": "Test Journey",
            "lastPublishedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "description": "",
            "version": 1,
            "workflowApiVersion": 1,
```

You should use the key, not the id.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I wish they had mentioned that in the documentation